# Force.com facebook toolkit integration

Tags: visualforce, force.com, remote-access, facebook

Was using the facebook Force.com toolkit https://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Getting_Started_with_the_Force.com_Toolkit_for_Facebook,_Version_3.0. Followed all the instructions as mentioned in the link.

I installed the toolkit and also configured the settings (public site creation).
I created a new facebook app as well. 
But after creating the app when I try to access the site.
(As mentioned in the following sentence of the installation guide: Go to your site URL (e.g. https://fbtest-developer-edition.na14.force.com/) and you should be prompted to log in to your new app and authorize it to access your data)

I am blocked and the following error shows up. [image]

Comment: Did you manage to resolve this? I am getting the same issue

Comment: Go to the site detail page and use the 'Preview as Administrator' link - you should get more detail as to what is going wrong.